# How to render nested modules, (parent outside articles)

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x, joomla-4

I tried the following code:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
$position   = 'precisions';
$options   = array('style' => 'raw');

echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
```

I can render modules anywhere I tried in php code, but I cannot render nested modules in templates files, as I could in articles… They are printed as raw placeholder, like `'{loadposition module}'`.

I tried to figure out what happens with the debugger, but seems that, at first, the nested modules is parsed, then, it is wipe out by the parent content.

What should I do to get the same result than Joomla inside articles, but in templates? How can I avoid this wipe out?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my bad… I forgot to put this code inside `mod_xxxxx.php`…

```
if ($params->def('prepare_content', 1))
{
    PluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
    $module->content = HTMLHelper::_('content.prepare', $module->content, '', 'mod_xxxxx.content');
}
```